# What could lead to " KeyError: 'Records' " in Lambda Edge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

KeyError: 'Records'
I use Lambd@Edge with CloudFront request original.
I could successfully pass the test event.
However, in cloudwatch I see errors:

[image]

According to documetation 'Records' should be present in the event.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html

Answer (score 2):

In reference to Request Events, this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html) says

> The following topics show the structure of the object that CloudFront passes to a Lambda function for viewer and origin request events.

These events are described as

> **Viewer Request**:
> The function executes when CloudFront receives a request from a
> viewer, before it checks to see whether the requested object is in the
> CloudFront cache.
>
> **Origin Request**: The function executes only when CloudFront forwards a
> request to your origin. When the requested object is in the CloudFront
> cache, the function doesn’t execute.

So it seems like you may be invoking the lambda in a way that does not cause the request event to be sent. If you are testing in the lambda console, try invoking it from cloudfront.

Comment: caught it. I invoke one of the versions from cloudWatchlogs

Comment: typo... Thank you!